# System.Drawing.Bitmap not recognised in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: bitmap, f#, system.drawing

I am writing a project in **F#** that uses the Bitmap functionality of System.Drawing, NET Standard 2.0, but the project can't be built because *The type 'Bitmap' is not defined in 'System.Drawing'*.

I have tried to add reference to System.Drawing in various locations and made sure I used the NET Standard library version. Also, I've repaired + reinstalled Visual Studio without any luck as well.

When right-clicking on the project and clicking 'Add Reference', I'm met with the following message. Could this be related to my issue?

[image: Error]

EDIT: As a slight plot twist/contradiction, I can execute the code in F# interactive where System.Drawing.Bitmap is perfectly accepted and compiling without any trouble. Where could the error lie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the `System.Drawing` functionality is not available in .Net Core. (There are too many dependencies to native Windows libraries) You can either switch to .net framework or include third party packages like https://github.com/CoreCompat/System.Drawing

Answer (score 3):

It is available in this Nuget package (although in preview version yet, still works fine)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/